# How are XMPP/ejabberd login sessions represented/maintained in each message sent? How does it compare to PHP Sessions?

Tags: session, authentication, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how a user can send a message after login since there is no exchange of a session token or any other kind of token.

For example, in PHP after you login a user, a Session ID is created for him which is stored in a cookie, and then everytime he visits a page, that Session ID is retrieved from the cookie, identifying him.

How does this work with XMPP/ejabberd since no token is exchanged after authentication?

I found this:

> Session Manager: 
>   This module routes packets to local users. It searches for what user resource
>   packet must be sent via presence table. If this resource is connected to this
>   node, it is routed to C2S process, if it connected via another node, then the
>   packet is sent to session manager on that node.

... but I'm not sure it is related to my question and even if it is, I still don't get how does this relate to the login the user just made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XMPP, a TCP connection is kept open (often with TLS encryption). Every message sent over that connection is assumed to be from the user that has authenticated.

Session support given by the `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session` namespace is deprecated and most servers do nothing in response to `<session/>`.

Comment: Now everything makes sense, there's a reason it has the presence subscription then. XMPP is a beast, and I'm still scratching its surface. Thank you!